# Cirrus or Adobe Media Server

Tags: flash-media-server, adobe-cirrus

What is the difference between using Cirrus or FMS? What are the pros and cons the limitations and advantages of each?

Thank You

Comment: they are completely different, for what purpose do you need them?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to make a small video chat application. I am debating which to use. I dont know which is the most suitable. Do they both have have the same features?

Comment: no, not at all. fms is media server, while cirrus is a peer to peer udp technology allowing direct connection between client flash player apps (first you have to connect a `NetConnection` to cirrus host which gives you your connection id, then you have to pass such id of another client app to a `NetStream` that uses a `NetConnection` connected to cirrus host in the first app to establish connection between them); however you have to use some other server technology for exchanging cirrus connection ids between clients

Answer (score 0):

this link might be helpful http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/
`Unlike Adobe Media Server,Cirrus does not support media relay, shared objects, scripting, etc. So by using Cirrus, you can only develop applications where Flash Player endpoints are directly communicating with each other.`